# Addition and subtraction of values of two columns when using Orange GUI

Tags: orange

I am a new user to the Orange GUI.

I would like to know if there is anyway I can add or subtract two columns and then return the result as a new column?

Answer (score 2):

Use **Feature Constructor** like so:

[image]

and **X1** will be the name of your new feature (you can obviously change it)